# О реализации python на C

Tags: python, c

Пользователи Stack Overflow!
Возможно, мой вопрос многим покажется слишком общим, не по тематике этого сайта.
Вот собственно о чем я хотел спросить: отличны ли CPython и python по синтаксису? Какой версии python он "соответствует" по возможностям и функционалу, и что нужно для того, чтобы начать программировать на нем (среда разработки)?

**Upd**: Так как я понял, что python==CPython, то не могли бы вы ответить на вопросы выше (только о **Cython**)?

Comment: CPython - это и есть "обычный" Python, его стандартная реализация. А вот Cython - другая реализация, которая имеет свой синтаксис, фактически это другой язык.

Comment: @insolor спасибо